# Simple way to truncate a string in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a string that must be truncated at 200 characters if it is too long.

Checking the [cheatsheet](http://clojure.org/cheatsheet), `(subs "Lorem Ipsum" 0 200)` would seem to be an obvious choice, but it throws an exception if the second operator is greater than the length of the string.

Is there a simple, built-in function for truncating a string in Clojure?  What's the simplest way to do this if I have to define my own?

Comment: I'd check to see if the length of the string is greater than 200. If it is then substring to 200 characters otherwise don't substring at all.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can check the length beforehand or use `min` to determine the actual number of characters that will remain:

```
(defn trunc
  [s n]
  (subs s 0 (min (count s) n)))
```

Comment: this is good, especially since strings are a counted type in the jvm, so count is a O(1) operation.

Comment: you might, as a precaution, want to check that s for nil-ness.

Comment: and check n for negative values

Answer (score 8):

You can treat them as sequences and get safety (and elegance?) but the cost is performance:

```
(defn truncate
  [s n]
  (apply str (take n s)))
```